# Microsoft Custom Speech Service to accept audio file and transcription one by one

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I created a Custom Acoustic Model (which includes a set of audio files of speech data in a zip file, and the transcriptions of each audio file separated by a tab in a text file) and imported it. After creating the deployment, I tried testing the endpoint by uploading an audio file and it returned the text transcription as expected.

But here's the plan: merging the OOB acoustic model that Microsoft is providing with the Custom Speech. Tried the WPF example (https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows) which returns 4 speech-to-text transcriptions. What we want is for **each** message (one audio file), the user is provided those 4 transcriptions and he will choose which one is correct.

Now we want to feed the recorded audio file and the correct transcription to the Custom Speech Service. How do we **programmatically import the acoustic data and create a model for it** (instead of manually uploading the whole zip file of audios and the text file with the key-value pair of the file name and transcription and so on)? (Edit the existing Acoustic Data every time, not Import a new one)

Or if we cannot feed it one by one (every time the user has finished talking), we can just collect the audio files first to a zip file then collect the file names and transcriptions in a text file once the whole conversation has ended. But still the problem is how to programmatically do the importing and modeling. Or is it even possible.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Out of curiosity What audio file format did you feed in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Speech Service does not currently offer APIs to programmatically carry out what you described. There is however a plan in place to release APIs in the coming months.

Comment: Custom Speech Speech (cris.ai) offers currently a portal only experience where users can import their data, create custom models, deploy them and access them via some endpoint. There is a plan to support these operations via APIs in the future